# Execute stored query containing "function" in access db from excel

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to run a query stored in access database from excel vba. The query runs fine if I open and run it in access database but causing error while running it from VBA module.
The query uses a stored function called "Getlist" which is in access database module. Below is the query.

```
SELECT paramconcat.parameter, GetList("Select concat From paramconcat As T1 Where T1.parameter = """ & [paramconcat].[parameter] & """","",", ") AS Concatenated INTO results
FROM paramconcat
GROUP BY paramconcat.parameter;
```

**VBA Module**

```
Sub test1()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
With con
 .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
 .Open "C:\Users\erukhq\Documents\My Received Files\paramcheck.accdb"
End With
con.Execute "ParamconcatQ"
con.Close
End Sub
```

**The error I am getting is as below**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can only use built-in, native VBA functions in queries that are called from outside of Access, so your custom function will work when running the query inside Access, but it will not work when called via ADO.

You'll also need an ADODB.Command object.

`'...
    Dim cmd as ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    Cmd.CommandText = "yourqueryname"
    Cmd.CommandType = acCommandUnknown 'you might need to try different values of the CommandType enum.
    Cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    Set rst = new ADODB.record set
    Rst.open cmd`

Comment: You can use *native* VBA functions like Left and Mid, but you can't use custom functions, or Access functions, or functions from referenced libraries.

Comment: Is there anyway to convert the user defined function to native function?

Comment: I just noticed you're calling the query by name using the Execute method. I don't think the connection recognises it, and that's the case of your current error.  You'll need to add an ADODB.Command object into the mix.

Comment: Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
   With cmd
      .ActiveConnection = conn
      .CommandText = "ParamconcatQ"
      .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
   End With
 
  I get Error **Undefined function getlist in expression**